# Receiver:null error when trying to save form using globalKey

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following this https://medium.com/@c_innovative/simple-firebase-login-flow-in-flutter-6f44c2b5c58a tutorial and i am having some trouble with getting the login in to work. I have already connected my app to firebase and enabled email and password authentication on firebase console!

I have tried entering the key argument into the TextFormfield but so far im unable to do so.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginPageState();
  }
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email;
  String _password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Login Page Flutter Firebase"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Spacer(flex: 5),
              Text(
                "Login  Information",
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
              Spacer(
                flex: 5,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                key: _formKey,
                onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email Address"),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
              ),
              Spacer(flex: 3),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Login"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    //Getting the error here
                    final form = _formKey.currentState;
                    form.save();

                    if (form.validate()) {
                      print('$_email $_password');
                      var result = await 
                      Provider.of<AuthService(context).loginUser(email: _email, password:_password);
                      if (result == null) {
                        print("result is null");
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              Spacer(
                flex: 20,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'save' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: save()

this error message is what i get. somehow i understand that i have to initialise the receiver object(?) but i am confused on how to do so. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you put the `_formKey` on the `TextFormField` associated with the email field, it doesn't belong there

```
 body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  ....
                 ]
            ) // Form
         ) // Container
```

From the blog post..
[image]

Comment: hi aaron, i added it in to try and troubleshoot. Where should i place my _formkey? doing the final form = _formKey.currentState;  form.save(); line still throws the error of me calling save on null!

Comment: see edits, also it looks like you missed a step in the blog post, although you can use `TextEditingControllers` i think it over complicates the example

Comment: I see ! Big mistake on my part! Thanks for taking the time to look at my code! Really appreciated! thanks for guiding flutter noobs like me >< !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onSaved I'd just use `TextEditingControllers` on your fields and get the values of the text from those when you call your signIn function.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please don't forget to mark the question as solved if this answer was sufficient.